# EF Database first - Change datatype of a column from BigInt to Int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have changed the data type of a column in my sqlserver DB from BigInt to Int. i want to the update the same in my application which uses EF, In my EDMX file i have deleted the corresponding table and using Update Model from DB i have added back the table again.

In my DTO files i see that the property still has its data type as Long.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is affecting you. Remove the table from the diagram. Save. Then update model from DB, add it back and Save. Saving is what causes the generation of the code and it might be that you just missed that step and the code file wasn't getting dropped and recreated.